# Update array of specific object under an object Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aded60f6e89ea0e60e00e59"),
    "mail" : {
        "count" : 1,
        "messages" : [ 
            {
                "message" : "xyz",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-07-25T10:51:15.915Z"),
                "view" : 0
            },
            {
                "message" : "abc",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-07-26T10:51:15.915Z"),
                "view" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I have to update the View from 0 -> 1 on first object that is "timestamp": "ISODate("2018-07-25T10:51:15.915Z")".

For this I am writing the code but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
db.Collection.updateOne({'_id': ObjectId("5aded60f6e89ea0e60e00e59"), 'mail.messages.timestamp': 'ISODate("2018-07-25T10:51:15.915Z")'}, {$set: {'mail.messages.$.view': 1}})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
}) 



//I run this query on my mongodb shell and there it works perfectly. But when i write same query on my node js then it returns the error that is "typeError: callback.apply is not a function. This error arises when i mention false, true on my query at last i.e 
db.Collection.updateOne({"_id": ObjectId("5aded60f6e89ea0e60e00e59"), "mail.messages.timestamp": "2018-07-26T10:51:15.915Z"}, {$set: {"mail.messages.$.view": 1}}, false, true)
```

Anyone suggest me that where I am doing wrong on not appropriate. Any help is really Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You look to have single quotes around your dates in your find. So `'ISODate("2018-07-25T10:51:15.915Z")'` is just being used as a string, it should just be `ISODate("2018-07-25T10:51:15.915Z")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({_id :ObjectId("5aded60f6e89ea0e60e00e59"), "mail.messages.message" : "xyz"}, 
        {$set: {"mail.messages.$.view": 1}
        false, true);
```

Comment: I have to do this on timestamp basis not by message. that is 'mail.messages.timestamp' : 'ISODate("2018-07-25T10:51:15.915Z")'

Comment: please update ur question  , in your question , u have mentions to update where message is xyz

Comment: Updated the question. Please go through it